# Wake up an App using an hardware interrupt

Tags: ios

Is there a way I can program an app to wake up when the device receives a specific hardware interrupt?

For example, I created an IOT device which connects to the lightning port of my iPhone and I programmed my IOT device to send a specific device code (as an interrupt) when connected.

Will it be possible to code in way that the IOS detects this device code and knows that it has to wake a specific application (built for the device)? My use case is to make the application start automatically when the device is connected (even if the phone is in a locked state).

Comment: This would make a good enhancement request to file with Apple.

Comment: Any interaction with the Lightning Port is handled by the MFi program. You would need to join that in order to pursue this. However, i doubt that you will be able to launch an app to the foreground as that is counter to the iOS user experience. You definitely won't be able to do it if the device is locked. Device locking isn't just something on screen with iOS. It is a fundamental state in the hardware. You can read the iOS security guide for more information.